# Bluemix IoT Foundation - read-only access?

Tags: mqtt, ibm-cloud, iot

With and API Key/Token combination we can connect from an application and subscribe/publish to any topic.

Is there a way to prevent an application from publishing to a topic (eg. read-only access) ?

Is it possible to limit the topics an application can connect to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this functionality is not available, they expect to add it in the very near future

Answer (score 0):

The topic space in which devices and applications operate is scoped within a single organization. The IoT Foundation uses the org ID to isolate topics so data from one organization is not accessible by another.    Is that what you are asking or do you want to specifically prohibit applications that authenticate within the same org from publishing to a topic within the same org space?

Comment: Thanks Valerie, yes, I'm talking about application/devices within the same organization. I want to prevent an application from publishing to a topic but with the current key/token credentials it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: We expect to be adding this functionality in the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in terms of applications and devices, are you wanting applications to only be able to subscribe to topics (events) for devices, rather than publish to topics (commands) for devices?  Also, do you want to control which applications can work with (publish / subscribe) to a certain set of devices?

Comment: Henry, All that I need is to prevent an application from publishing. I don't need it on a app to device level.